# Why isn't this code to capture/prevent CTRL+S in jquery/javascript working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, key-bindings

I was struggling for a long time to get my code to work and tried a variety of answers on StackOverflow that all took generally the same form. Eventually, I settled on this:

```
$(window).bind('keydown',function(e) {
    if ((e.which=='115' || e.which=='83') && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
        e.preventDefault();
        saveForm(); // Uses AJAX to save all the data in my form 
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I tried as far as combinations of binding to window, document, keydown, keypress, nothing is working and the save dialogue comes up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Because I use the `saveForm()` function on page unload to make sure data is saved before the navigate away, I had to set the ajax function to be asynchronous. This meant there was a race condition between saving and reaching the `return false` statement which, when I commented out the `saveForm()` call, seemed to be the thing that works (I don't know why `preventDefault` didn't stop it, but it didn't).

To solve the race condition, I considered setting a variable to choose when to do the save synchronously or asynchronously, but realized I could avoid the race condition entirely by delaying the save until after I had fully canceled the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key combination. Here is the final version of my code that works:

```
$(window).bind('keydown',function(e) {
    if ((e.which=='115' || e.which=='83') && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)){
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function(){saveForm();},200); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this, the `preventDefault` and `return false` both execute immediately and my save pops in a few milliseconds later.